# Flutter form without save button? (Auto save as user types)

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to build forms in Flutter that autosave forms without a Save button? What would be the mechanism? Checking for a timeout since last keystroke? Or save when the user navigates away from the screen?

Comment: Did you try onChange to save your entry? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#1-supply-an-onchanged-callback-to-a-textfield-or-a-textformfield

Comment: Not yet, but how could we limit this so Firebase is not inundated with requests?

Comment: you can put your conditions in onChange to limit send request